# Как определить степень схожести двух текстов?

Tags: алгоритм, сравнение, wavelet, текст

Допустим, взяли исходный текст, три абзаца. В его копии убрали полностью последнее предложение, поменяли адрес ссылки где-то в тексте, заменили пару предлогов, и заменили пару слов на синонимы.

Каков алгоритм, чтобы определить "эти тексты сходны на 65%. Скорее всего, общий первоисточник"? Есть ли что-то вроде вэйвлет анализа для текстов?

Comment: Если без теории, и не надо каких-то алгоритмических сертификатов, можно наверное сделать что то такое:
Сделать словарь слов из обоих текстов слово, добавить словарь синонимов, добавить к словарям текстов веса например по количеству слов в тексте. если слово является синонимом то умножаем на 0.5 к примеру. складываем эти веса. Вычитаем одно из другого и расхождение будет коэффициент различия.

Comment: @чад, т.е на порядок слов просто забили? : )

Comment: Из второго текста вычитаем первый, оставшаяся длина строки = мера. Примитивно конечно, зато просто реализовать.

Comment: @sergiks, а насколько похож текст: Мама мыла раму, и мыла Мама раму?

можно добавить меру например ещё, позиция в тексте. Я описал общую идею :-)

В идеале конечно - разбираем на лексемы, нормализуем и сравниваем их... Но формализовывать русский язык....

Comment: - Попробую предложить свой велосипедный вариант - вы можете попробовать разбить текст на предложения (или какие-то их более мелкие части, типа части сложных предложений), а дальше провести попарное сравнение таких частей по [метрике Левенштейна.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

- Утверждается, что для предложений (или их элементарных частей), которые есть "суть одно и то же", значение этой метрики не будет превышать какого-нибудь мелкого порога, типа `~5-7%` от длины части. Для абсолютно разных частей это значение, предположительно будет намного болье.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В биоинформатике подобные вопросы - определение схожести двух разных последовательностей нуклеиновых кислот или протеинов (читай - текстов) - составляют основную проблему. Решается она с помощью разных [алгоритмов выравнивания](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9). В вашем случае можно применить метод глобального выравнивания - самого простого из них. Подробнее о нем читай по указанной ссылке. Если будет непонятно, порекомендую литературу.

Comment: Я правильно понял: это поможет определить длины совпадающих фрагментов. Если абстрагироваться от замены на синонимы, можно считать степенью схожести отношение суммарной длины совпавших фрагментов (длиннее 1 буквы) к общей длине исходного текста?

Comment: Можно просто подсчитать отношение количества совпадающих букв к общему числу. К сожалению, алгоритм глобального варавнивания плохо работает при крупных перестановках. Для этого есть другие алгоритмы.

Comment: @mikillskegg, я не особо в этом деле разбираюсь, но альтернативу вы привели классную, правда! Плюсую =). Хотелось бы немного почитать об этом. Не могли бы вы "порекомендовать литературу" ?

Comment: @Asen, для начала можно почитать Хаубольд, Вие "Введение в вычислительную биологию"

Comment: @mikillskegg, а Вы реально работали в этой области?

Comment: @avp, это типа хобби)) Я по образованию генетик.

Comment: ОК. Конечно не в тему - как Вы оцениваете "Геном" Ридли?

Comment: Не читал, не знаю.

Answer (score 8):

[Алгоритм шинглов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).

> Алгоритм шинглов — алгоритм, разработанный для поиска копий и дубликатов рассматриваемого текста в веб-документе, мощный инструмент, призванный бороться с проявлениями плагиата в интернете.

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже на рабочий вариант.

Comment: Да, это не шутка. Но может медленно работать + проблема канонизации **русского** языка.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее шутка и очень простой ответ. Подозреваю что автору не подойдет.

Надо вычесть из единицы отношение длины вывода утилиты `diff` к сумме длин текстов.

Конечно, `diff` сравнивает по строкам, но это можно обойти довольно просто, выводя каждое слово в отдельной строке.

Comment: Остроумно : )