# Поиск дублей объявлений. Какие действия?

Tags: php

Доброго времени. На сайте часто дублируют объявления, не всегда получается  запоминать и модерировать  .

Поделитесь мыслями, как можно искать дубли (скриптово) ? 
На данный момент сделал поиск с одинаковой почтой или контактами + текстом , но этого недостаточно, т.к в тексте  могут одну букву заменить .

Знаю, что нет 100% универсального метода, но любые рекомендации будут кстати .Спасибо!

Comment: http://www.php.su/functions/?similar-text

Comment: задавал похожий вопрос: [Как определить степень схожести двух текстов?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/149893/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача обширная и трудоемкая. Но если не стоит задача написать ИИ, а просто создать некий механизм, который сигнализировал бы модератору о подозрениях на сходные сообщения, то можно попробовать.

В первую очередь я думаю следует ограничиться сравнением только сообщений от одного автора. Определять что это один автор, можно по e-mail или по контактам. Как я понял из вопроса - это вы уже умеете.

Поэтому собственно задача сводится к созданию некоторого алгоритма, который бы получал на входе два текстовых сообщения, а на выходе выдавал бы некоторый коэффициент показывающий насколько эти сообщения похожи друг на друга. А дальше уже исходя из показаний этого коээфициента скрипта решает что деалть: либо пропустить сообщение, либо сигнализировать модератору, что возможно это дубль.

Насчет алгоритма, я бы предложил следующий вариант:

1. Полученные данные приводим к общему виду. Проще всего разбить сообщение на "слова". Т.е. преобразовать строку в массив слов. В качестве разделителя для такой операции стоит использовать любые пробельные символы (пробле, табуляция, перевод строки и т.д.), а так же знаки пунктуации (точка, запятая, тире, двоеточие, точка с запятой и т.д.)
   В результате получится массив слов.
2. Дальше чистим массив от "мусора". Убираем дубли слов, а так же убираем слова, короче 2 или 3 символов (можно определить опытным путем). Так же можно убрать разлиные мусорные слова: "потому", "чтобы" и т.п.. Для этого можно завести отдельный массив таких слов и вносить туда слова по мере использования алгоритма и отладки его работы.
3. Дальше считаем одинаковые слова. И я бы рекомендовал считать в обе стороны. Т.е. считаем сколько слов из первого массива есть во втором, а потом сколько слов из второго есть в первом. Так же на этом этапе можно ввести понятие "ключевых слов". Т.е. некоторый массив слов, которые важны для вашей области. Т.е. если у вас сообщения о продаже автомобилей, то в такие "ключевые слова" можно добавить марки автомобилей. Так же можно добавить их с некоторыми весами. Если совпадают слова в массиве, то счетчик совпадений просто увеличивается на единицу. Если же совпадают слова из списка ключевых, то счетчик увеличивается на вес этого слова.
4. Считаем коэффициент совпадения. Самый простой способ это посчитать отношение совпадений в массиве к количеству элементов в этом массиве. Для удобства восприятия информации можно умножить это отношение на 1000. В результате будет два числа от 0 до 1000. В качестве коэффициента совпадения можно взять максимальное из полученных чисел.

В результае будет функция которая будет в качестве аргументов получать две строки, а возвращать число от 0 до 1000. Что делать дальше с этим числом - надо уже смотреть опытным путем. Например для начала поставить сигнализацию о совпадениях, если это число больше 500. Затем смотреть насколько правильно будет работать алгоритм. Если будет много разных сообщений, то границу увеличиваем. Если же будут попадаться только одни дубли - то границу можно сдвинуть вниз - вдруг что-то не учитывается.

В общем как мне кажется алгоритм простой и легко реализуется на любом языке программирования и без особых изысков. И к тому же есть простор для оптимизации и подгона под конкретные примеры.